# How to add subdomains by defining new zones in a local DNS server

Tags: networking, server, dns, kvm-virtualization, bind

I have a local server which I am managing multiple VMs with **Qemu-KVM** under ubuntu 18.04. Local server has already a static IP and a domain name given from our company IT, say the domain name **main.company.com**. I am running web applications on each VM and each VM has an internal IP(starting with 192.168) that speaks with main server and an external IP which is reachable from  (starting with 172.18).

What I want to achieve is to be able to reach to running web applications with a URL containing subdomain definition of the running application from intranet. Let's say with URL http://elk.main.company.com I should reach to kibana web application running in a VM on port 80.

I have tried to setup the main server with forward and reverse zones with bind9 as main.company.com as DNS server and hosts with A name records by using their local(192.168) and private(172.18) IPs but couldn't achieved what I wanted. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I understand that you have only an A record assigned to main.mycompany.com. You can't add subdomain names to an A record. You can add subdomain names to a **zone**.

You need to have a **NS record** (one or more) defined for main.mycompany.com that points to the machine(s) where you have BIND installed (this is called *domain delegation*). Then you can define zones in that BIND configuration.

Using my domain `rafa.eu.org` as an example:

There is an A record assigned to `rafa.eu.org`:

```
raj@jarek-02:~$ host -t a rafa.eu.org
rafa.eu.org has address 217.182.79.14
```

but there are also (in this case three) NS records for that domain:

```
raj@jarek-02:~$ host -t ns rafa.eu.org
rafa.eu.org name server e.ns.buddyns.com.
rafa.eu.org name server new.rafa.eu.org.
rafa.eu.org name server c.ns.buddyns.com.
```

Primary name server for the domain is `new.rafa.eu.org` (which is in fact the same IP address as `rafa.eu.org`, the prefix "new" is left from the time I was migrating my server from one hosting company to another - the IP addresses were different at that time and some services were already migrated to "new" server while some were still left on the "old" one) and I could define any subdomains of rafa.eu.org in BIND configuration on that server. The other two name servers are secondary name servers that just pick up configuration from the primary server (I used a popular free secondary NS service).

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it says that main.mycompany.com has no NS record when I checked it with host -t ns. So, let's say I ask for that and our IT added an NS record for this domain, then is it going to be straightforward to achieve what I want? do I need to define through internal IPs (192.168.122 inside kvm) or through private network IPs (172.18 in company network) ?

Comment: @Rikkas once the NS record is added and you define the "main.mycompany.com" zone in your BIND configuration, it should work. What IPs you should define depends on what will be the usage of the domain names. If you want the domain names to be usable only inside KVM, use 192.168.122 network. If you want them to be usable throughout corporate network, use 172.18.

Comment: @Rikkas You mentioned reverse zones in your question as well - if you want to define reverse zones, you also need NS records for `122.168.192.in-addr.arpa` and/or `18.172.in-addr.arpa` to point to your machine.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed guidance.